# Begin and commit transaction in interceptor

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, transactions, interceptor

Is it good practice to have interceptors to manage transactions?
I have a strong point though that it is equivalent to begin and commit in the action itself.
Why should I use interceptor managed transactions at all?

[image]

Comment: Where did you see such interceptor?

Comment: Hi Roman,one of my friend suggested that he is using it the same way but I found no point in it as this can lock the database cells until a result is returned from action.

Comment: Do you have an example? Could you show how it locks the db?

Comment: See transaction begin and commit appear in interceptor so the value read during the operation will not be modified until whole processing is done.In fact the modification has to wait for other operations to be completed before it is actually reflected to db.Now think of the logical unit of work(transaction) taking longer time for completing.During this time if some other transaction has read the same data & tries to modify it before previous one then the previous one will be roll-backed. In concurrent execution environment this can lead to multiple transaction roll-backings.

Comment: What a error is issued or how do you know the transaction is roll-backed?

Comment: I haven't written code for this though if I use optimistic locking this should happen. & BTW its a well established DB concept for concurrent transactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not bad practice, for example Spring framework uses aspects for 'auto-begin' and 'auto-commit' transactions using `@Transactional` annotation.

```
Why should I use interceptor managed transactions at all?
```

It reduces a lot of boilerplate code: opening connection, beginning transaction, committing transaction and closing connection.

But if you want to write your own transaction manager using interceptors - beware of concurrency issues

According to image you posted:

It's better not to expose transaction management from Service layer. It's better if your presentation layer don't know anything about Transaction management. So try to encapsulate your  transaction management code in service layer or in DAO layer. If your presentation layer manages transaction and service layer is not, it's mean your services is not self-contained, and they can be reused by other client only if client provide some transaction management logic.

From Comments:

> Better is to put transaction management code to service layer, because
>   service layer usually performs some business level operations, which
>   must be performed within one transaction. So your service method can
>   use 2 or more DAOs to perform all DB operations in one transaction.
>   Sorry, there is no links - I tell it your from my experience.

Comment: thanks for the reply.But how will you counter for this that this can lock the database cells until a result is returned from action.

Comment: @amit_yo see updated answer. What about database locks - why you need to remove lock from DB row when performing action? Lock prevents data from being corrupted or invalidated when multiple users try to read while others write to the database etc. If you want to lock DB rows only to required time for performing DB operation - then use transactions only on DAO layer (but in general it's better to delegate transaction management to Service layer)

Comment: thank you.
About locking in database please read my comment to my question.
Please tell which one is better way to manage transaction at service layer or DAO layer and why? It will be helpful if you can provide some reference or link. Thank again.

Comment: 1. `if some other transaction has read the same data & tries to modify it before previous one then the previous one will be roll-backed` - why you decide so? What API you using? It not entirely true, it's entirely framework/API specific. 2. Better is to put transaction management code to service layer, because service layer usually performs some business level operations, which must be performed within one transaction. So your service method can use 2 or more DAOs to perform all DB operations in one transaction. Sorry, there is no links - I tell it your from my experience.

Comment: OK I got you. but previous one should be roll-backed as it has read an old value & modification on old value is not desirable. I am using Hibernate.

Comment: +1. Also use Hibernate as JPA 2 implementation instead of raw hibernate, and don't care about transactions at all, they're automatic for most of the things you need (after you set up all correctly, and from Java EE 6 of course).